# Как просмотреть список подписчиков в UCOZ?

Tags: ucoz

Необходимо просмотреть список подписчиков на сайте под управлением ucoz. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оказалось что всё просто. Необходимо зайти в "пользователи", "массовая рассылка" "список подписчиков"